# Can't set callback while loading user timeline using Fabric Twitter Kit in Android application

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using Fabric Twitter Kit for loading user timelines. However, I am not able to make callbacks work properly. I follow the official examples, but still my `success` and `failure` methods are not called.

Here is my full code:

```
public class TwitterFragment extends ListFragment {


    final Callback<Tweet> callback = new Callback<Tweet>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
            setListShown(true);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NotFail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startWork();

    }

    public void startWork() {

        final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().screenName(Config.TWITTER_ACCOUNT).build();
        final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(getActivity())
                .setOnActionCallback(callback).setTimeline(userTimeline).setViewStyle(R.style.tw__TweetDarkStyle).build();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.twitter_layout, container, false);
    }

}
```

Any ideas how to make everything work?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm on the same boat?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up figuring it out.

The `Callback`'s type needs to be `TimelineResult. Your code should look like this:

```
final Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>> callback = new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result) {
            Log.d("TAG", "success");
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failure");
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(getActivity()).setTimeline(userTimeline).build();
    userTimeline.next(null, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call

```
//for the first time
userTimeline.next(null, callback);
```

after that you can provide last tweet Id as first argument to get tweets after the last tweet id.

You are not loading any tweets, that's all.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am loading the tweets. My evidence is that I can see them on the screen. And the code is written according to the examples on the Fabric website